# Visual Studio - Javascript Intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

**EDIT:** The duplicate question does not address my issue. I have done everything specified there but JS Intellisense is not working. I have all four files in the script references directory (`jquery-2.1.4.js`, `jquery-2.1.4.min.js`, `jquery-2.1.4.min.map`, and `jquery-2.1.4.intellisense.js`) and I've added the global reference to `jquery-2.1.4.js`, but Intellisense does not work. I do not have a `_references.js` file.

I've been using Visual Studio for about nine months now and I just discovered on another site that VS has Javascript Intellisense support. I cannot figure out how to enable it, however; I've never had it. VS always says `Intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression. The provided list contains all identifiers in the file.`, I've just ignored it. I have a file in `~/Scripts` called `jquery-2.1.4.intellisense.js`, it's always been there, but I've never had Intellisense.

How do I enable Javascript Intellisense in VS? Does it support standard Javascript or only packages I add (such as jQuery)? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from the other 4 answers in the duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was adding the jQuery references to the `Implicit (Windows)` section of the References tab in Options. I switched to `Implicit (Web)` and added jQuery there, the problem is resolved.